# Check Constraint Expression error

Tags: sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I'm trying to create a Check Constraint using SQL Server Management Studio 2012's wizard to allow a field to be null only if the tuple is not enabled, but I'm getting an `Error validating constraint`.

The expression I'm trying to use is this:

```
TransactionalMerchantId IS NOT NULL
OR
(TransactionalMerchantId IS NULL AND Enabled IS false)
```

My table is designed as this:

[image: Table Merchant]

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
TransactionalMerchantId IS NOT NULL
OR
(TransactionalMerchantId IS NULL AND Enabled = 0)
```

Comment: Nailed it! Forgot SQL Server didn't automatically render `false` as 0. Thanks!

Comment: This has caught me up a few times. I'm guessing this is so queries with integer types aren't easily incorrectly written (by evaluating the integer value as a boolean, accidentally), similar to many languages comparing equality with == but assignment with =.

Answer (score 0):

`is` is for comparing with `null` only.  Try:

```
[Enabled] = false
```

Comment: partially right, but according to @Jake Heidt's post, sql server doesn't understand false or true, only 0 or 1. But thanks for the insight anyways!